# Adding new sheets with date names stored in dynamic array

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays, vba

I am using Excel 2007 and trying to create a code that will name particular worksheets of an active workbook by dates of current month. So far, I managed to create an array that includes all dates of current month but I am having issues with applying elements of that array as sheet names. The the line of code: ***ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name.Add = MyArray(N)*** does not work. Any help with altering the code would be greatly appreciated as I am a newbie to VBA:

```
Sub CreateSheetsWithNamesAsDatesOfCurrentMonth()

Dim x1 As Date
Dim x2 As Integer
Dim BOM As Date
Dim x4 As Date
Dim x5 As Integer
Dim EOM As Date
Dim N As Integer
Dim DaysBetween As Integer
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long

x1 = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now) + 1)
x2 = Day(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now)))
BOM = x1 - x2

x4 = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 1, Day(Now))
x5 = Day(DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 1, Day(Now)))
EOM = x4 - x5

DaysBetween = EOM - BOM


For N = 0 To DaysBetween

ReDim MyArray(N To DaysBetween)

MyArray(N) = DateAdd("d", N, BOM)

Next N


For N = 0 To LBound(MyArray)


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(N).Name.Add = MyArray(N)

Next N

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment is wrong, you `Add` to the `Sheets` collection with a `Name`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Name:=MyArray(N)
```

Note: the values in the array *may* need to be converted to `String` type and ensure removal of illegal characters like `/`:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Name:=Replace(Cstr(MyArray(N)), "/", vbNullString)
```

Comment: @trix do consider marking the answer as Accepted, if it's helped solve the question